# How to use MediaPlayer properly with Kotlin to reproduce sounds?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I have two buttons (one for successes and another one for fails). I want to reproduce a different sound when clicking on each button. Each button will be clicked like 100 times before destroying the current activity.

I want to interrupt both sounds if they are playing while clicking on any of the buttons, to avoid hearing two sounds simultaneously. To do that, I've created a function named `stopSounds()` which is called when clicking any of the buttons.

Besides, I am releasing both sounds when destroying the activity. Should I release them in other part of the app, for example each time they finish playing?

This is the summary of my code:

```
class MyClass : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var successSound: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var failSound: MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        this.successSound.release()
        this.failSound.release()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ...
        val successBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_success)
        val failBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_fail)
        ...
        this.successSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.success)
        this.failSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fail)
        ...
        successBtn.setOnClickListener {
            this.stopSounds()
            this.successSound!!.start()
        }
        failBtn.setOnClickListener {
            this.stopSounds()
            this.failSound!!.start()
        }
    }

    private fun stopSounds() {
        if (this.successSound?.isPlaying == true) {
            this.successSound!!.stop()
            this.successSound!!.prepare()
        }
        if (this.failSound?.isPlaying == true) {
            this.failSound!!.stop()
            this.failSound!!.prepare()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it Ok? Can I improve it? Should I use SoundPool instead? Any advice, corrections or examples will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.